# JavaScript output not iterating correctly

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to clone a row then renaming the element id's and incrementing one of the values by 1. This is not the actual code I'm working on but a generic example that shows the problem.

- It is appending everything to the top of my row instead of below it
- It increments once or twice then stops

The output I'm getting is:

- 10022018
- 10032018
- 10032018
- 10032018
- 10032018
- 10012018

What I'm expecting is:

- 10012018
- 10022018
- 10042018
- 10052018
- 10062018
- 10072018

```html
    <table id = "myTable">
    <tr id="myRow">
    <td>First cell <input type="text" id = "input" value = "10012018"></td>
    
    
    </tr>
    </table><br>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
 var i;
    for(i=0; i<5;i++){
 var row=document.getElementById("myRow");           
 var cln = row.cloneNode(true);
    
    row.id = "rows" + i;
    var inpa = document.getElementById("input");
 inpa.id = "input" + i;                      

 var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input0").value);
    inpa.value = (a + 10000);                          
                      
 document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(cln);
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: The reason it "stops" incrementing is simply that you are only adding 10000 to the value of the element with id `"input0"`, which is the first one you added (the 10022018). This is why all subsequent additions are the value 10032018.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

Robin Zigmond added that `input0` was the culprit and not incrementing (corrected but I failed to explain).

> ```
> var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input0").value); // Should be "input"
> ```

---

> ```
> inpa.value = (a + (10000)); // Needs increment ...a + (10000 * i));
> ```

My explanation refers to this assignment to `row`.

> ```
> row.id = "rows" + i;  /* This assigns a new #id to the original not a clone
>  -- changed to `cln.id` */
> ```

---

When using a for loop leverage the incremental variable. When the clone was created, your references were still pointing to the original and it wasn't being used to increment anything so that's why it was just copying and not progressing.

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```html
<table id="xTable">
  <tr id="xRow">
    <td>First cell <input type="text" id="input" value="10012018"></td>


  </tr>
</table><br>

<button onclick="xFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
  function xFunction() {

    // In for loops declare i with let inside loop
    // Start with 1 instead of 0 because you cloned the increment starting at 1000
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

      var row = document.getElementById("xRow");

      var cln = row.cloneNode(true);

      // You are dealing with the clone not the original anymore
      // Use i form increments
      cln.id = "rows" + i;

      // Target the clone specifically
      // Use querySelector() to get #id, .class, or <tag>
      var inpa = cln.querySelector("input");

      // Once again var i to increment
      inpa.id = "input" + i;

      var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input").value);

      // Remember i to increment but this is a little trickier
      inpa.value = (a + (10000 * i));

      document.getElementById("xTable").appendChild(cln);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you! I knew it had to be something stupid I was overlooking.

Comment: No problem. On the contrary, it's a one off pattern so it's a tad trickier than the standard circumstances so it isn't stupid at all, especially if you learn from it.

Comment: I had to tweak it a bit to work in my actual script as it was quite a bit more complicated than this and a lot more rows and columns but it got me in the direction I needed and I definitely learned from it. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Id's** must be unique. Apply **class** to `tr` and `input` instead.

### A generic solution

```js
// n -> How many?
// start -> Start value
// index -> Index of value that should be incremented
// id -> Table id
function addRows(n, start, index, id) {
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  for (var i = 2; i <= n + 1; i += 1) {
    var arr = start.split("");
    arr[index] = i.toString();
    var incremented = arr.join("");
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.className = "row-" + i;
    var cell = tr.insertCell(-1);
    cell.textContent = "Cell ";
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = i + ": ";
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.className = "input-" + i;
    input.value = incremented;
    cell.appendChild(span);
    cell.appendChild(input);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="row-1">
    <td>Cell <span>1: </span><input type="text" class="input-1" value="10012018"></td>
  </tr>
</table><br>

<button onclick="addRows(5, '10012018', 3, 'myTable')">Try it</button>

<hr>

<table id="mySecondTable">
  <tr class="row-1">
    <td>Cell <span>1: </span><input type="text" class="input-1" value="14444"></td>
  </tr>
</table><br>

<button onclick="addRows(8, '14444', 0, 'mySecondTable')">Try it</button>
```